# REGEX for NOT matching phone number

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, phone-number

I'm trying to match anything that doesn't match my phone number format of `###-###-####`.

I have this to find a string of 10 digits

```
SELECT id, cust_num FROM `leads` WHERE cust_num REGEXP '[0-9]{10}'
```

This just finds anything that is 10 digits long.
Thats been good so far for finding entries where someone just typed a string of digits as a number,

However I want to find anything that doesnt match this format.

```
 555-555-5555
```

So I want to find any and all that don't match the above format

```
 /* For example, it should find all these*/
 5555555555
 555 555 5555
 (555)5555555
 555-555-555
 (555)-555-5555
```

What is the correct REGEX to find all that does not match `###-###-####`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT id, cust_num FROM `leads` WHERE cust_num NOT REGEXP '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution, just use `NOT`:

```
SELECT id, cust_num FROM `leads` WHERE cust_num NOT REGEXP '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
```

[**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp)